# How to remove/change top/bottom margin/padding on a table

Tags: tables, margins

I want to remove the margin/padding (I am not sure what it is) on my table so I can fit a header on the same page. I have tried slightly changing `\def\arraystretch{1.4}%` but I dont want the table to be to small.

[image]

```
\documentclass[norsk, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Gjør det mulig å bruke norske bokstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontenc 
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % Grafisk pakke
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}               % For å sette marginer
\usepackage{float}                              % Plassering av tab/fig
\usepackage{url}                                % Håntering av URL:er
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                   % Removes indent (works the same as \noindent )
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}                           % Brukes til a forandre mellomrom rundt overskrifter
\usepackage{natbib}                             % Bibliography
\usepackage{gensymb}                            % Adds symbols, as degree sign, etc.
%\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}                 % Setter inn innholdsfortengelse i innholdsfortengelse + nr. på referanser
\usepackage{afterpage}                          % For nye komandoer
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}               % For tabeller
\usepackage{tikz}                               % For organisazons kart
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}                           % Gant diagram
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}                       % Brukes i oversettning
\usepackage{translator}                         % Brukes til å oversette tekst fra \userpackage til annet
\usepackage{color}                              % Disse tre pakkene brukes i tabeller
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}                 % Viser dato \today i ISO format

\begin{document}

\section{Header}

\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.4}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\centering
\caption{Tabellen viser en oversikt over det som danner grunnlaget for Gantt-skjemaet i fugur }
\label{fig:prosjektplan}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Oppg.nr.} & \textbf{Oppgave}                                               & \textbf{Start}     & \textbf{Slutt}    & \textbf{Timer} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1}        & \textbf{Bacheloroppgave}                                       & \textbf{03. Mars}  & \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{637}   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.1}      & \textbf{Forprosjekt}                                           & \textbf{03. Mars}  & \textbf{23. Mars} & \textbf{75}    \\ \hline
1.1.1             & Innhenting av underlag fra oppdragsgiver                       & 03. Mars           & 22. Mars          & 30             \\ \hline
1.2.2             & Forprosjekt utkast                                             & 14. Mars           & 19. Mars          & 30             \\ \hline
1.2.3             & Forprosjekt revisjon                                           & 20. Mars           & 23. Mars          & 12             \\ \hline
1.1.4             & Innlevering av forprosjek                                      & 23. Mars           & 23. Mars          & 3              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.2}      & \textbf{Hovedprosjekt}                                         & \textbf{24. Mars}  & \textbf{07. Juni} & \textbf{518}   \\ \hline
1.2.1             & Designutvikling                                                & 24. Mars           & 15. April         & 160            \\ \hline
1.2.1.1           & Idemyldring                                                    & 24. Mars           & 2. April          & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.1.2           & Tegne og beregne intelligent design skisser for 3D-modellering & 01. April          & 15. April         & 80             \\ \hline
1.2.2             & 3D-modellering med Autodesk Inventor                           & 16. April          & 20. April         & 60             \\ \hline
1.2.3             & Teknisk analyser med ANSYS av 3D-modeller                      & 21. April          & 23. April         & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.3.1           & Analysere resultater fra analyser og velge beste design        & 23. April          & 24. April         & 4              \\ \hline
1.2.4             & Se på alternativene for 3D-printing av designet, og printe ut  & 24. April          & 30. April         & 60             \\ \hline
1.2.5             & Teste designet med virkelige tester                            & 30. April          & 03. Mai           & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.6             & Prosjektrapport                                                & 24. Mars           & 07. Juni          & 194            \\ \hline
1.2.6.1           & Skrive rapport                                                 & 24. Mars           & 28. Mai           & 160            \\ \hline
1.2.6.2           & Revisjon av midtveis rappor                                    & 08. Mai            & 10. Mai           & 6              \\ \hline
1.2.6.3           & Innlevering av midtveis rapport                                & 11. Mai            & 11. Mai           & 4              \\ \hline
1.2.6.4           & Revisjon av hoved rapport                                      & 28. Mai            & 31. Mai           & 18             \\ \hline
1.2.6.4           & Innlevering av hoved prosjekt                                  & 01. Juni           & 07. Juni          & 6              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.3}      & \textbf{EXPO}                                                  & \textbf{26. April} & \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{34}    \\ \hline
1.3.1             & Presentasjon                                                   & 07. Juni           & 14. Juni          & 22             \\ \hline
1.3.2             & Stand                                                          & 18. Mai            & 14. Juni          & 4              \\ \hline
1.3.3             & Pressmelding                                                   & 28. Mai            & 1. Juni           & 2              \\ \hline
1.3.4             & Prosjektbeskrivelse for katalog                                & 26. April          & 30. April         & 2              \\ \hline
1.3.5             & Prosjekttittel                                                 & 05. Juni           & 07. Juni          & 2              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.4}      & \textbf{Nettside}                                              & \textbf{3. Mars}   & \textbf{6. Juni}  & \textbf{10}    \\ \hline
1.4.1             & Opprettelseavnettside                                          & 3. Mars            & 31. Mars          & 2              \\ \hline
1.4.2             & Driftavnettside                                                & 3. Mars            & 6. Juni           & 6              \\ \hline
14.3              & Ferdigstillelseavnettside                                      & 6. Juni            & 6. Juni           & 2              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[Working code.](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/kmxfgpmwhfhn)

Comment: please merge both code sniped to one small but complete document. in it from preamble remove all packages which are not related to page layout and table. please also clarify what you mean by `margin/padding`. are this gray lines which show your page layout? if this is the case, just remove `\usepackage{showframe} `

Comment: @Zarko I am not talking about the frame, but whatever that makes the table go on a separate page. I can only get the header and the table on the same page if i remove \def\arraystretch{1.4}, but I don`t want the table to be to small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the table to stay on the same page with `[h!]`

Off-topic:

- using `\resizebox` for text is not a good idea, select an appropriate fontsize instead, see [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296) for some explanation
- `hyperref` should be loaded after the other packages (with only very few exceptions)
- you don't need `color` if you have `xcolor`
- You might want to read http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

---

```
\documentclass[norsk, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Gjør det mulig å bruke norske bokstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontenc 
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % Grafisk pakke
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}               % For å sette marginer
\usepackage{float}                              % Plassering av tab/fig
\usepackage{url}                                % Håntering av URL:er
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                   % Removes indent (works the same as \noindent )
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}                           % Brukes til a forandre mellomrom rundt overskrifter
\usepackage{natbib}                             % Bibliography
\usepackage{gensymb}                            % Adds symbols, as degree sign, etc.
%\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}                 % Setter inn innholdsfortengelse i innholdsfortengelse + nr. på referanser
\usepackage{afterpage}                          % For nye komandoer

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}               % For tabeller
\usepackage{tikz}                               % For organisazons kart
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}                           % Gant diagram
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}                       % Brukes i oversettning
\usepackage{translator}                         % Brukes til å oversette tekst fra \userpackage til annet
\usepackage{color}                              % Disse tre pakkene brukes i tabeller
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}                 % Viser dato \today i ISO format
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Header}

\begin{table}[h!]
\def\arraystretch{1.4}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\centering
\caption{Tabellen viser en oversikt over det som danner grunnlaget for Gantt-skjemaet i fugur }
\label{fig:prosjektplan}
\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Oppg.nr.} & \textbf{Oppgave}                                               & \textbf{Start}     & \textbf{Slutt}    & \textbf{Timer} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1}        & \textbf{Bacheloroppgave}                                       & \textbf{03. Mars}  & \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{637}   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.1}      & \textbf{Forprosjekt}                                           & \textbf{03. Mars}  & \textbf{23. Mars} & \textbf{75}    \\ \hline
1.1.1             & Innhenting av underlag fra oppdragsgiver                       & 03. Mars           & 22. Mars          & 30             \\ \hline
1.2.2             & Forprosjekt utkast                                             & 14. Mars           & 19. Mars          & 30             \\ \hline
1.2.3             & Forprosjekt revisjon                                           & 20. Mars           & 23. Mars          & 12             \\ \hline
1.1.4             & Innlevering av forprosjek                                      & 23. Mars           & 23. Mars          & 3              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.2}      & \textbf{Hovedprosjekt}                                         & \textbf{24. Mars}  & \textbf{07. Juni} & \textbf{518}   \\ \hline
1.2.1             & Designutvikling                                                & 24. Mars           & 15. April         & 160            \\ \hline
1.2.1.1           & Idemyldring                                                    & 24. Mars           & 2. April          & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.1.2           & Tegne og beregne intelligent design skisser for 3D-modellering & 01. April          & 15. April         & 80             \\ \hline
1.2.2             & 3D-modellering med Autodesk Inventor                           & 16. April          & 20. April         & 60             \\ \hline
1.2.3             & Teknisk analyser med ANSYS av 3D-modeller                      & 21. April          & 23. April         & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.3.1           & Analysere resultater fra analyser og velge beste design        & 23. April          & 24. April         & 4              \\ \hline
1.2.4             & Se på alternativene for 3D-printing av designet, og printe ut  & 24. April          & 30. April         & 60             \\ \hline
1.2.5             & Teste designet med virkelige tester                            & 30. April          & 03. Mai           & 22             \\ \hline
1.2.6             & Prosjektrapport                                                & 24. Mars           & 07. Juni          & 194            \\ \hline
1.2.6.1           & Skrive rapport                                                 & 24. Mars           & 28. Mai           & 160            \\ \hline
1.2.6.2           & Revisjon av midtveis rappor                                    & 08. Mai            & 10. Mai           & 6              \\ \hline
1.2.6.3           & Innlevering av midtveis rapport                                & 11. Mai            & 11. Mai           & 4              \\ \hline
1.2.6.4           & Revisjon av hoved rapport                                      & 28. Mai            & 31. Mai           & 18             \\ \hline
1.2.6.4           & Innlevering av hoved prosjekt                                  & 01. Juni           & 07. Juni          & 6              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.3}      & \textbf{EXPO}                                                  & \textbf{26. April} & \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{34}    \\ \hline
1.3.1             & Presentasjon                                                   & 07. Juni           & 14. Juni          & 22             \\ \hline
1.3.2             & Stand                                                          & 18. Mai            & 14. Juni          & 4              \\ \hline
1.3.3             & Pressmelding                                                   & 28. Mai            & 1. Juni           & 2              \\ \hline
1.3.4             & Prosjektbeskrivelse for katalog                                & 26. April          & 30. April         & 2              \\ \hline
1.3.5             & Prosjekttittel                                                 & 05. Juni           & 07. Juni          & 2              \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{1.4}      & \textbf{Nettside}                                              & \textbf{3. Mars}   & \textbf{6. Juni}  & \textbf{10}    \\ \hline
1.4.1             & Opprettelseavnettside                                          & 3. Mars            & 31. Mars          & 2              \\ \hline
1.4.2             & Driftavnettside                                                & 3. Mars            & 6. Juni           & 6              \\ \hline
14.3              & Ferdigstillelseavnettside                                      & 6. Juni            & 6. Juni           & 2              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
%}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

of-topic, since your main problem is solved by accepted [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) answer :-)

- to make more open look of table (not have cells in prison) i would redesign your table as follows:

  - remove all vertical and horizontal lines
  - for table environment use `tabularx` that the table width is equal to text width
  - use standard font size
  - not stretch table rows
- with document example below show, what is expected that a mwe (minimal working example) should be. it should contain only what is needed to reproduce your problem

```
\documentclass[norsk, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Gjør det mulig å bruke norske bokstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % fontenc
\usepackage[hmargin={3cm,2.5cm},
            vmargin=3cm]{geometry}  % For å sette marginer
% removed to problem irrelevant packages
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}   % For tabeller
% removed to problem irrelevant packages
%\usepackage{color}   % not needed, `xcolor` is superceded of `color`
\usepackage{booktabs,
            tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Header}
\begin{table}[ht!] % this option solve your basic problem 
    \centering
\caption{Tabellen viser en oversikt over det som danner grunnlaget for Gantt-skjemaet i fugur}
\label{fig:prosjektplan}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l >{\raggedright}X lll }
    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\textbf{Oppg.nr.}
    & \textbf{Oppgave}
                & \textbf{Start}     & \textbf{Slutt}     & \textbf{Timer}     \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{1}      & \textbf{Bacheloroppgave}
                    & \textbf{03. Mars} & \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{637}  \\
    \addlinespace
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{1.1}    & \textbf{Forprosjekt}
                    & \textbf{03. Mars} & \textbf{23. Mars} & \textbf{75}   \\
1.1.1           & Innhenting av underlag fra oppdragsgiver
                    & 03. Mars          & 22. Mars          & 30            \\
1.2.2           & Forprosjekt utkast
                    & 14. Mars          & 19. Mars          & 30            \\
1.2.3           & Forprosjekt revisjon
                    & 20. Mars          & 23. Mars          & 12            \\
1.1.4           & Innlevering av forprosjek
                    & 23. Mars          & 23. Mars          & 3             \\
    \addlinespace
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{1.2}    & \textbf{Hovedprosjekt}
                    & \textbf{24. Mars} & \textbf{07. Juni} & \textbf{518}  \\
1.2.1           & Designutvikling
                    & 24. Mars          & 15. April         & 160           \\
1.2.1.1         & Idemyldring
                    & 24. Mars          & 2. April          & 22            \\
1.2.1.2         & Tegne og beregne intelligent design skisser for 3D-modellering
                    & 01. April         & 15. April         & 80            \\
1.2.2           & 3D-modellering med Autodesk Inventor
                    & 16. April         & 20. April         & 60            \\
1.2.3           & Teknisk analyser med ANSYS av 3D-modeller
                    & 21. April         & 23. April         & 22            \\
1.2.3.1         & Analysere resultater fra analyser og velge beste design
                    & 23. April         & 24. April         & 4             \\
1.2.4           & Se på alternativene for 3D-printing av designet, og printe ut
                    & 24. April         & 30. April         & 60            \\
1.2.5           & Teste designet med virkelige tester
                    & 30. April         & 03. Mai           & 22            \\
1.2.6           & Prosjektrapport
                    & 24. Mars          & 07. Juni          & 194           \\
1.2.6.1         & Skrive rapport
                    & 24. Mars          & 28. Mai           & 160           \\
1.2.6.2         & Revisjon av midtveis rappor
                    & 08. Mai           & 10. Mai           & 6             \\
1.2.6.3         & Innlevering av midtveis rapport
                    & 11. Mai           & 11. Mai           & 4             \\
1.2.6.4         & Revisjon av hoved rapport
                    & 28. Mai           & 31. Mai           & 18            \\
1.2.6.4         & Innlevering av hoved prosjekt
                    & 01. Juni          & 07. Juni          & 6             \\
    \addlinespace
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{1.3}    & \textbf{EXPO}
                    & \textbf{26. April}& \textbf{15. Juni} & \textbf{34}   \\
1.3.1           & Presentasjon
                    & 07. Juni          & 14. Juni          & 22            \\
1.3.2           & Stand
                    & 18. Mai           & 14. Juni          & 4             \\
1.3.3           & Pressmelding
                    & 28. Mai           & 1. Juni           & 2             \\
1.3.4           & Prosjektbeskrivelse for katalog
                    & 26. April         & 30. April         & 2             \\
1.3.5           & Prosjekttittel
                    & 05. Juni          & 07. Juni          & 2             \\
    \addlinespace
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{1.4}    & \textbf{Nettside}
                    & \textbf{3. Mars}  & \textbf{6. Juni}  & \textbf{10}   \\
1.4.1           & Opprettelseavnettside
                    & 3. Mars           & 31. Mars          & 2             \\
1.4.2           & Driftavnettside
                    & 3. Mars           & 6. Juni           & 6             \\
14.3            & Ferdigstillelseavnettside
                    & 6. Juni           & 6. Juni           & 2             \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did follow yours and @samcarter advice!

Comment: @Niklas, i slightly improve code and add missing `\end{document}` . you can (instead thank you) up vote my answer when you will have enough reputation. happy tex-ing